# GA4 Measurement Protocol does not match the client through client_id

Tags: google-analytics

Our webpage client (website) collects the **client_id** and send it to our backend-server when the user submits a form. Then on the backend we use the Measurement Protocol API to send the (conversion) event when the submitted form is confirmed.

While posting data to GA4 Measurement Protocol API, we are adding the client_id as well.

```
End point: www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=G-XXX&api_secret=XXX

{
 "client_id": "101571251.1653627906",
 "events": [
   {
    "name": "test_event_6",
    "params": {
      "test_param_1": "50",
      "test_param_2": 80
    }
   }
 ]
}
```

**However**, when I check the GA4 reports, even though I can see the event in the real-time reports, the event is not associated with any real client.

What could be the issue here? How can we debug it?

Comment: please edit your question include your code, describe what you are sending and what you are seeing in the reports show the issues.

Comment: Did you came up with any solution to this? I am sending the same way as you do, i have all the informaion about the event/product in GA but no information about user.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did any of you find out any more information regarding this?

Comment: I have not found any solution. I have tried many approaches. I am almost sure I've done everything as expected. I think this is not working any more.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried sending a session_id and engagement_time_msec?

`In order for user activity to display in standard reports like Realtime, engagement_time_msec and session_id must be supplied as part of the params for an event.`

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=gtag#recommended_parameters_for_reports

Comment: could you teach me how to get session_id and engagement_time_msec for GA4 on web application?